# angular $http.get() is not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am newbie, can somebody help me to get this fixed.

My code:

```
myApp.controller('myController', function($scope, $http) {    
    $http({
        method : "GET",
        url : "http://localhost:8081/contact"
    }).then(function successCallback(response){
        console.log("success");
        $scope.records = response.data;
    }, function errorCallback(response){
        console.log("error");
    })
});
```

Comment: Please share the error you're seeing in console

Comment: i can't see any error message, the http function can't fetch data from url :(

Comment: Is the page running on same port 8081 as the api? Are you seeing the "error" message in console?

Comment: there are no "error" message in console

Comment: What's wrong then? What do you expect to happen vs. what's actually happening?

Comment: i change the port and restart server, it still not works

Comment: <div ng-repeat="x in records">
            {{x.name}}     {{x.email}}      {{x.number}}</div>

  
this does not print anything

Comment: Can you print out `response` for the success & error callbacks and put those in your question?

Comment: Which browser did you test in?